# Integer/String comparision works in 3.35.5 but not in 3.43.0

Tags: sqlite

the following code works on 3.35.5 SQLite version but not on 3.45.0
in this case the problem is that due to some inner working of the engine, it manages to compare integer and string. But that doesnt happen in higher versions.

We have several hundred SQLite queries. Is anyone familiar with this issue, if there is any approach except brute force to solve this or at least identify queries that have a similar issue?

The following code is simplify so it isnt dependent on database tables , but still showcases the issue.

Thank you

```
WITH cte_ParseList (ItemNumber, MaxItemNumber, StrToParse, ParsedElement, OrderTypeClKey) AS
        (
        SELECT 
          0, 3, '2;0|3;0|5;0|', '', 30
        UNION ALL SELECT 
          1, 3, '3;0|5;0|', '2;0', 30
        UNION ALL SELECT 
          2, 3, '5;0|', '3;0', 30
        UNION ALL SELECT 
          3, 3, '5;0','' ,30
    )    ,
    cte_ParseClKey (OrderTypeClKey, SalesTeamId, ItemNumber, MaxItemNumber, StrToParse, PstCl1ClKey)
    AS
    (
     SELECT
      OrderTypeClKey,
      CAST(SUBSTR(ParsedElement, 0, instr(ParsedElement, ';')) AS INTEGER),
      0,
      LENGTH(ParsedElement) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ParsedElement, ';', '')),
      SUBSTR(ParsedElement, instr(ParsedElement, ';')+1),
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(256))
     FROM  cte_ParseList
     WHERE ItemNumber > 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
      OrderTypeClKey,
      SalesTeamId,
      ItemNumber + 1,
      MaxItemNumber,
      SUBSTR(StrToParse, instr(StrToParse, ';')+1),
      SUBSTR(StrToParse, 1,CASE WHEN instr(StrToParse, ';') = 0 THEN LENGTH(StrToParse) ELSE instr(StrToParse, ';')-1 END)
     FROM cte_ParseClKey
     WHERE ItemNumber < MaxItemNumber
    )
    SELECT
     typeof(cte_ParseClKey.PstCl1ClKey ) AS PstCl1ClKey ,
     typeof(COALESCE(CL_KEY,0)) AS CL_KEY,
     CL_KEY, cte_ParseClKey.PstCl1ClKey,COALESCE(CL_KEY,0),
     CASE 
        WHEN cte_ParseClKey.PstCl1ClKey = COALESCE(CL_KEY,0) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END AS [WHEN BOTH are 0 AND '0' this should be 1]
    FROM cte_ParseClKey
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS ok, 0 AS CL_KEY UNION ALL SELECT 0,CAST(NULL AS INT) ) AS Codelist500 ON ok = 0
```